# Can a class definition contain that class' pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I'm trying to define a class this way (simplified):

```
class Student
{
    private:
        Student* pointer;
    public:
        set_pointer(Student*);
}
```

Is this legal in C++ and is it consistent with object oriented design?

Comment: Yes, it's legal. Whether it is a good design depends on what you are going to do with it.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Why are you answering in the comments section?

Comment: @Lightness Because I wanted to. And because I assumed it was a dupe.

Comment: Could somebody please tell us in what way this could be *inconsistent* with OO design?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Both bad reasons. Okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a class may store a pointer to an object of the same type (which may be itself, or some other instance).

This is common in linked-list implementations, where a node stores a pointer to the *next* node.

As for whether it's "consistent with object oriented design", it is impossible to make a generalisation on the subject; it depends on the program. Personally I cast a suspicious eye on code of this form, but again you can't really generalise.

Comment: Such classes are "recursively defined".

Comment: So you cast a suspicious eye on linked lists?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: No, they're not.

Comment: @EJP: Sometimes.

Comment: Sometimes *why*? How about trees?

Comment: @EJP: Generally anything that isn't a data structure gets the suspicious eye.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, yes they are.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: A recursively defined class is impossible, but you could write a non-compiling program that contains one like this: `struct T { T child; };`

Comment: @Lightness, data structures like a `tree` (or "linked-list") are said to be recursively defined because their backing `node` classes are indeed recursively defined (a `tree` can just be the root `node` in an application; the `tree` is just a convenience/generalization of a structure with a single node as a root). With the list we have `node *next;` inside the `node` class. I understand there are limitations as you suggest, however, because a `node` has a pointer to a `node` doesn't change that the class is defined using its own definition; meaning a `node` has one or more `node`s.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: This is a difference in terminology coming from different layers of abstraction. From the C++ perspective, it's what I said above. From a computer science/mathematical perspective I guess you could define it any number of ways.